# Can't set root dir of vsftpd

Tags: arch-linux, vsftpd

My Arch Linux 4.20.2 serves files without a problem from [`vsftpd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon)'s default root directory, `/srv/ftp/`.

The only addition I made to the config file at `/etc/vsftpd.conf` is

```
seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

This gets rid of the following error displayed in Firefox when accessing the files:

> 500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd

This is all great, but I'd like to serve files from a different directory, say `/home/jenkins`.

Consulting [the manual of `vsftpd.conf`](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/vsftpd.conf.5), I added this to `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
anon_root=/home/jenkins/
```

Hoping to make the change effective, I called `systemctl restart vsftpd`.

Yet, `vsftpd` (I'm using version 3.0.3) still serves the files in its default root directory, `/srv/ftp/`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, `systemctl restart vsftpd` did not make the changes effective.

Using `pgrep vsftpd`, I observed that two of the three processes that are spawned with `systemctl start vsftpd` had survived after me calling `systemctl restart vsftpd`. That's why the old configuration was still in use.

The solution was to call

```
pkill vsftpd; systemctl start vsftpd
```

Now, `vsftpd` serves the files under the directory specified in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` with

```
anon_root=/home/jenkins/
```

instead of the files in the default root directory, `/srv/ftp/`.